# How to make a list of some chosen sections？

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, cross-referencing

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\raggedbottom       %reduce underfull \vbox

\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
%change the part format in book 
\titleformat{\part}[frame]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\partname\ \thepart }{20pt}{\Huge\centering}
%change the part format in table of contents
\titlecontents{part}%
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\huge\protect\addvspace{25pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{\partname~}
{\hfill\contentspage}%replaced with {} if don't want page number for parts
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{10pt}]%remove rule if you like

%change the chapter format in table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}%
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
{\chaptertitlename\ \thecontentslabel~}{}
{\hfill\contentspage}%
[\addvspace{1.5ex}]%

%change the appendix name from chapter to appendix
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*{\protect\chaptername}{\protect\appendixname}}%
}
\makeatother
%force paragraph newline
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}


%insert figures
\usepackage{graphicx}

%improve the interface for defining floating objects such as figures and tables
\usepackage{float}

%customize page layout
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

%color
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%page headers and footers   left,right,odd,even
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\normalfont\small\rmfamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\normalfont\small\rmfamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

%booktitle
\title{\Huge C++ \\\qquad\textcolor{RedOrange}{Primer}}
\author{\textbf{Stanley B.Lippman} \and \textbf{Jos\'ee Lajoie} \and \textbf{Barbara E.Moo}}
\date{}

%motto
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center} %center
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt} %cancel the line between words and person name

%code
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Visual]C++,
                basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                keywordstyle=\color{NavyBlue}\ttfamily,
                stringstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\ttfamily,
                commentstyle=\color{PineGreen}\ttfamily,
                morecomment=[l][\color{RedViolet}]{\#},
                columns=flexible, %cancel monospced characters
                showstringspaces=false %not show space
}

%change the width of lrbox( lrbox is the environment form of \sbox, which is similar to \mbox)
\usepackage{varwidth}

%change baseline of pictures(eg: valign)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}



%type­sets text in mul­ti­ple columns (up to a max­i­mum of 10)
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{15pt}

%revise\@endpart macro
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\bigbreak} 
\makeatother

%use \cmidrule \toprule
\usepackage{booktabs}


% add mini-ta­bles-of-con­tents (mini­tocs) at the be­gin­ning of ev­ery chap­ter, part or sec­tion.
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1} 
\renewcommand\tightmtcfalse

%set two text form
\definecolor{Kblue}{rgb}{0.24,0.36,0.65}
\newcommand\known[1]{\textcolor{Blue}{\emph{#1}}}
\newcommand\vital[1]{\textcolor{Cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}
%initialize minitoc
\dominitoc 


\frontmatter
\maketitle
\chapter*{Preface}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Important Sections}
\ref{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram} \nameref{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram} \hfill \pageref{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram}\\
\ref{subsec:The while Statement} \nameref{subsec:The while Statement} \hfill \pageref{subsec:The while Statement}\\
\ref{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions} \nameref{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions} \hfill \pageref{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Getting Started}
\minitoc 
    \section{Writing a Simple C++ Program}
        \subsection{Compiling and Executing Our Program}\label{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram}

    \section{A First Look at Input/Output}
    \section{A Word about Comments}
    \section{Flow of Control}
        \subsection{The while Statement}\label{subsec:The while Statement}
        \subsection{The for Statement}
        \subsection{Reading an Unknown Number of Inputs}
        \subsection{The if Statement}\label{subsec:The if Statement}
    \section{Introducing Classes}   
        \subsection{The Sales\_item Class}
        \subsection{A First Look at Member Functions}\label{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions}
    \section{The Bookstore Program}
    \section*{Chapter Summary} \markright{Chapter Summary} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter Summary}
    \section*{Defined Terms} \markright{Defined Terms} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Defined Terms}

\part{The Basics}
\chapter{Variables and Basic Types}
\minitoc 
    \section{Primitive Built-in Types}
        \subsection{Arithmetic Types}
        \subsection{Type Conversions}
        \subsection{Literals}

\appendix
\chapter{The Library}
    \section{Library Names and Headers}


\backmatter

\chapter{Index}
\chapter{New features in C++11}

\end{document}
```

I want to list some sections which I think important in chapter 'Important Sections'? I find a stupid way to do it that I use `\ref`, `\nameref` `\pageref` on each important section. But I have too many sections to list, is there anyway smarter?

[image]

Comment: The `\ref` etc. way isn't the worst idea in my point of view...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have too many sections to list. So many \ref etc seems a little stupid.

Comment: Off-topic: `titlesec` and `minitoc` are not compatible to each other

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i know, but I haven't found a way to customize my mini-ta­bles-of-con­tents at the beginning at some chapters with titletoc. The minitoc package offers a easy way. And my program can run normally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows the idea to use `\implabel` instead of `\label` in order to indicate an important section.

All such labels are stored in a `\seq` list from `expl3` and written later on to the `.aux` file as a comma - separated list with `\label{allimportantsections}` at the end of the document automatically, at the begin of the document, this label is retrieved and the list of read labels is filled.

The macro `\DisplayImportantSections` typesets the references within a `tabularx` environment.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft}X}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_robert_importantlabels_seq
\seq_new:N \g_robert_importantlabels_read_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addlabel}{m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_robert_importantlabels_seq {#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\looplabels}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_robert_importantlabels_read_seq {
    \DisplayImportantSecEntry{##1}
  }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn {Nx}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\seq_use:Nn \g_robert_importantlabels_seq {,}}
  \label{allimportantsections}
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nx \g_robert_importantlabels_read_seq {\getrefnumber{allimportantsections}}
}

\makeatother



\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayImportantSections}{}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rXY}
    \looplabels
  \end{tabularx}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DisplayImportantSecEntry}{m}{%
 \ref{#1} & \nameref{#1} &  \pageref{#1} \tabularnewline
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\implabel}{m}{%
  \label{#1}%
  \addlabel{#1}%
}



\raggedbottom       %reduce underfull \vbox

\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
%change the part format in book 
\titleformat{\part}[frame]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\partname\ \thepart }{20pt}{\Huge\centering}
%change the part format in table of contents
\titlecontents{part}%
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\huge\protect\addvspace{25pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{\partname~}
{\hfill\contentspage}%replaced with {} if don't want page number for parts
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{10pt}]%remove rule if you like

%change the chapter format in table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}%
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
{\chaptertitlename\ \thecontentslabel~}{}
{\hfill\contentspage}%
[\addvspace{1.5ex}]%

%change the appendix name from chapter to appendix
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand*{\protect\chaptername}{\protect\appendixname}}%
}
\makeatother
%force paragraph newline
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}


%insert figures
\usepackage{graphicx}

%improve the interface for defining floating objects such as figures and tables
\usepackage{float}

%customize page layout
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

%color
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%page headers and footers   left,right,odd,even
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\normalfont\small\rmfamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\normalfont\small\rmfamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

%booktitle
\title{\Huge C++ \\\qquad\textcolor{RedOrange}{Primer}}
\author{\textbf{Stanley B.Lippman} \and \textbf{Jos\'ee Lajoie} \and \textbf{Barbara E.Moo}}
\date{}

%motto
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center} %center
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt} %cancel the line between words and person name

%code
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Visual]C++,
                basicstyle=\ttfamily,
                keywordstyle=\color{NavyBlue}\ttfamily,
                stringstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\ttfamily,
                commentstyle=\color{PineGreen}\ttfamily,
                morecomment=[l][\color{RedViolet}]{\#},
                columns=flexible, %cancel monospced characters
                showstringspaces=false %not show space
}

%change the width of lrbox( lrbox is the environment form of \sbox, which is similar to \mbox)
\usepackage{varwidth}

%change baseline of pictures(eg: valign)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}



%type­sets text in mul­ti­ple columns (up to a max­i­mum of 10)
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{15pt}

%revise\@endpart macro
\makeatletter
\def\@endpart{\bigbreak} 
\makeatother

%use \cmidrule \toprule
\usepackage{booktabs}


% add mini-ta­bles-of-con­tents (mini­tocs) at the be­gin­ning of ev­ery chap­ter, part or sec­tion.
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1} 
\renewcommand\tightmtcfalse

%set two text form
\definecolor{Kblue}{rgb}{0.24,0.36,0.65}
\newcommand\known[1]{\textcolor{Blue}{\emph{#1}}}
\newcommand\vital[1]{\textcolor{Cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}
%initialize minitoc
\dominitoc 


\frontmatter
\maketitle
\chapter*{Preface}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Important Sections}

\DisplayImportantSections

%\ref{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram} \nameref{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram} \hfill \pageref{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram}\\
%\ref{subsec:The while Statement} \nameref{subsec:The while Statement} \hfill \pageref{subsec:The while Statement}\\
%\ref{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions} \nameref{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions} \hfill \pageref{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Getting Started}
\minitoc 
    \section{Writing a Simple C++ Program}
        \subsection{Compiling and Executing Our Program}\implabel{subsec:compiling and executing our rogram}

    \section{A First Look at Input/Output}
    \section{A Word about Comments}
    \section{Flow of Control}
        \subsection{The while Statement}\implabel{subsec:The while Statement}
        \subsection{The for Statement}
        \subsection{Reading an Unknown Number of Inputs}
        \subsection{The if Statement}\label{subsec:The if Statement}
    \section{Introducing Classes}   
        \subsection{The Sales\_item Class}
        \subsection{A First Look at Member Functions}\implabel{subsec:A First Look at Member Functions}
    \section{The Bookstore Program}
    \section*{Chapter Summary} \markright{Chapter Summary} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter Summary}
    \section*{Defined Terms} \markright{Defined Terms} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Defined Terms}

\part{The Basics}
\chapter{Variables and Basic Types}
\minitoc 
    \section{Primitive Built-in Types}
        \subsection{Arithmetic Types}
        \subsection{Type Conversions}
        \subsection{Literals}

\appendix
\chapter{The Library}
    \section{Library Names and Headers}


\backmatter

\chapter{Index}
\chapter{New features in C++11}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A preliminary version, still editing!

Comment: Can you add a leader(dots) between the section name and the page

Comment: @K.Robert: Your screen shot does not have leaders, please don't change the question

Comment: Don't worry, I won't.

Comment: @K.Robert: Well, you're requesting leaders  which were not in your question above...